# Using /dev/tcp with proxy

Tags: bash, wget, proxy

Is it possible to use `/dev/tcp` with a proxy? I only found `wget` is possible to use with proxy, but `wget` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked the sources of `bash 4.2`: the proxy support for `/dev/tcp` and `/dev/udp` is not implemented.

The only option you have is to start a copy of `bash` with [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/) library preloaded (see `man tsocks` for details)

So, you would also need to set up a [socks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy server.